# Saving/Loading TableView With NSUserDefaults Xcode

Tags: objective-c, xcode, tableview

I'm sort of new to Xcode and I would like to know how to save and load a tableview with all its cells that the USER created with NSUserDefaults. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Have you done some tutorials around UITableViewController? That should help you to get started.

Answer (score 0):

One of the ways on MacOS (very similar on iOS):

1. Create a model object which will keep your data. Don't use NSUserDefaults to save data for the table view. You should check NSCoding protocol doc. how to archive and unarchive objects.
2. To populate table view, implement required NSTableViewDataSource protocol methods. To update the table view, update underlying data model and reload the table.

There are other ways using NSArraycontroller, binding, but I suggest reading some basic "how to populate" NSTableView/UITableView tutorials first.